# find foldernames and store in array, if path has spaces

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a `find` command that returns several folders which may contain spaces. I'd like to test these and store them in an array. I've tried 2 things, which both don't work.

## capture find output directly

```bash
found=()
for folderpath in $(find "$myrootfolder" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name ".*" -type d); do
  # check if they have a file install.sh
  if [ -f "$folderpath/install.sh" ]; then
    found+=("$folderpath")
    echo "$folderpath"
  fi
done
echo "---contents of found array:"
for f in ${found[@]}; do echo $f; done
```

What doesn't work here, is that the loop is ran multiple times for one folder, if its path contains spaces. There should be 2 elements in the `found` array, but there are 4:

Output:

```
/mnt/c/Users/first.last/my
documents/scriptroot/folder1
/mnt/c/Users/first.last/my
documents/scriptroot/folder2
---contents of found array:
/mnt/c/Users/first.last/my
documents/scriptroot/folder1
/mnt/c/Users/first.last/my
documents/scriptroot/folder2
```

## pipe

```bash
found=()
find "$myrootfolder" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name ".*" -type d | while read folderpath; do
  # check if they have a file install.sh
  if [ -f "$folderpath/install.sh" ]; then
    found+=("$folderpath")
    echo "$folderpath"
  fi
done
echo "---contents of found array:"
for f in ${found[@]}; do echo $f; done
```

Here the problem is, that the part after the pipe runs isolatedly or something like that; there should be 2 elements in the `found` array, but there are 0:

```
/mnt/c/Users/first.last/my documents/scriptroot/folder1
/mnt/c/Users/first.last/my documents/scriptroot/folder2
---contents of found array:
```

Any other creative ideas? Pure `bash` if possible.

Comment: so why not just `for i in "$myrootfolder"/*/`? `Any other creative ideas?` See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: never do that! - https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: `mapfile -d '' found < <( find "$myrootfolder" -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name install.sh -type f -printf '%h\0' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
found=()
for d in "$myrootfolder"/* 
do
   [[ -f $d/install.sh ]] && found+=( "$d" )
done
```

or, if you know for sure that you don't happen to have a **directory** named `install.sh`,

```
found=()
shopt -s nullglob
for f in "$myrootfolder"/*/install.sh
do
  found+=( "$(dirname "$f")" )
done
```

(Setting *nullglob* ensures that the the loop is skipped if no install scripts are found).

Comment: That first one worked (I added quotes around `$d` to be sure) - many thanks!

Comment: Ah, forgot the quotes. Will fix it.

Comment: The quotes are needed in the array assignment. Fixed this.

Comment: `$(dirname "$f")` should also be quoted

Comment: @Ivan : Thanx. Missed that. I'm already too spoiled from zsh.

Answer (score 0):

Um, why are you searching dirs if you interested in a file? Try it like this:

```
while read a; do
    arr+=( "$(dirname "$a")" )
done < <(find "$myrootfolder" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name install.sh)
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `find` is something better avoided .... See the comment by _Inian_ to the original question (in particular point 3 in the page s/he is linking to). You could of course get around the problem by using `-print0` and then employ an appropriate setting of `IFS` to split the input on the NULs.

Comment: Oh, missed `-maxdepth 1`